# Google Recaptcha tag not show in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I have integrated the secret key and site Key in the contact form 7. Not able to see the captcha tag in contact form 7 list
[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this documentation by Contact form 7 https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/  with the latest versions of contact form 7 there is a mentioning as:

`reCAPTCHA v3 doesn’t need a CAPTCHA widget (the “I’m not a robot” checkbox used in reCAPTCHA v2) to work, so [recaptcha] form-tags are no longer necessary. If [recaptcha] form-tags are found in a form template, Contact Form 7 5.1 or higher ignores them and replaces them with an empty string.`

So seems like it already integrated into the contact form 7 so all you need is to integration the keys with the contact form 7 integration section and rest it will configure for you.